# Single query to get the messages and count their answers

Tags: mysql, count, subquery

I have a mysql DB with two tables:

- messages
- message_answers

I'd like to fetch all messages and the number of answers for each of them, like:

- first message (10 answers)
- second message (5 answers)

Is it possible with a single sql query ?

I tried a query and a subquery for the count, but I don't know how to have the current id from the main query to make the "WHERE" restriction on the subquery (like: "message_answers.message_id = messages.id").

Thank you,
Sébastien

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT m.message, COUNT(ma.answer_id) AS AnswerCount
    FROM messages m
        LEFT JOIN message_answers ma
            ON m.id = ma.message_id
    GROUP BY m.message
```

Comment: Thank you!
When I see the answer, I think that my question was really stupid! :)

Comment: True, it's just that I am angry not to have found by myself. 
Anyway, thank you! ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
select m.id, count(ma.id)
from messages m
join join message_answer ma on ma.id = m.message_id
group by 1
```